# Why are some file changes not shown in tail -f?

Tags: files, mysql, tail

I tried to follow the mysql history file with:

```
tail -f ~/.mysql_history
```

in another window I entered as the same user:

```
mysql -u someotheruser -p
```

and none of the following commands are shown in my tail.
when I exit the mysql console there is still nothing shown in the `tail -f`, although, when I `cat` the history file, I see, that there are new entries at the end of the file

Comment: Follow-up in [How can I monitor a file that fully recreates during its run?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103161/22565)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `mysql` fully recreates `.mysql_history` file during its run.

So when you run `cat ~/.mysql_history` after `mysql` execution, you're looking completely different file. Not the one `tail` is reading.

You can easily check it with a simple test:

```
 $ ls -li .mysql_history 
6685441 -rw------- 1 user user 1570 Sep 15 21:26 .mysql_history
 $ mysql i_test
...
mysql> Bye
 $ ls -li .mysql_history
6685474 -rw------- 1 user user 1592 Nov 29 20:27 .mysql_history
```

as you can see inode differs. So that's the answer.

Comment: GNU tail has a `-F` option that will periodically reopen the file by name so that it can work in cases like this.

Comment: That will add the whole file to the tail -F each time you leave the mysql console. Isn't there another way to watch the progress om the file? maybe with `watch` somehow?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: [How can I monitor a file that fully recreates during its run?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103161/how-can-i-monitor-a-file-that-fully-recreates-during-its-run)